# Split a CSV file into two equal size groups having a criteria

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, split

There are many similar questions about this but none were close to my issue.

I would like to split a csv data into two groups of equal length having equal criteria, here is Age. Also, the harder problem could be to combine multiple criteria for the sampling, which could be Age && Work Experience && Management Exp, so the outcome is as normalized as possible.

I understand this is an optimization problem of NP (or harder complexity) and perhaps there won't be a closed-form or definite answer, but a close enough would be good.

```
import random
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

classlist = pd.read_csv('Classlist-Test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(classlist)
grouped = df.groupby(['Age'])

grouped.sum()
     Work Experience (Yrs)  Management Experience (Yrs)
Age
23                       1                            1
24                      14                            2
25                      15                            8
26                      42                           10
27                      44                            5
28                      30                            8
29                      21                            3
30                      19                            6
31                      44                           12
32                      37                            5
33                      31                            9
34                      21                           12
35                      18                            1
36                      24                            0
38                      21                            4
39                      35                           16
40                      28                           18
41                      15                            7
45                      49                           17
46                      20                           11
53                      25                           10

>>> df.mean()
Age                            30.158879
Work Experience (Yrs)           5.177570
Management Experience (Yrs)     1.542056
dtype: float64
>>> df.median()
Age                            28.0
Work Experience (Yrs)           4.0
Management Experience (Yrs)     0.0
dtype: float64
>>> df.std()
Age                            5.557843
Work Experience (Yrs)          4.580132
Management Experience (Yrs)    2.533848
dtype: float64
```

Any suggestions on how to do that in Python? Is there a sampling method that does this?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think optimization is a good option here. You want to look into nearest neighbors and pair matching methods. You can find a lot  online about this .

Comment: Calculate the cumsum of Age and determine the 50% value, then split your dataset at that value into two groups. With more criteria this could work similarly.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, this seems to be almost like a percentile at 50%, but again, If I split it there I will have two classes one with above and the other with lower average. I want both to have the same mean at the end.

Comment: In general it is not possible to ensure that both groups will have the same mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `train_test_split` with the `stratify` option, and a `test_size` of 0.5 as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age": np.random.randint(0,50,10000),
                   "work_exp" : np.random.randint(0,3,10000),
                   "man_exp" : np.random.randint(0,3,10000),
                   "value": np.random.randint(0,2,10000)})
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.5, 
                                     stratify=df[["Age", "work_exp", "man_exp"]], random_state=0)
```

Here is the result for the main statistics of both `df_train` and `df_test`:

```
> df_train.describe()
              Age     work_exp     man_exp        value
count  5000.000000  5000.000000  5000.00000  5000.000000
mean     24.516600     1.014200     1.01520     0.493400
std      14.453107     0.820812     0.81431     0.500006
min       0.000000     0.000000     0.00000     0.000000
25%      12.000000     0.000000     0.00000     0.000000
50%      24.000000     1.000000     1.00000     0.000000
75%      37.000000     2.000000     2.00000     1.000000
max      49.000000     2.000000     2.00000     1.000000
```

```
> df_test.describe()
              Age     work_exp      man_exp       value
count  5000.00000  5000.000000  5000.000000  5000.00000
mean     24.47900     1.011200     1.009400     0.51000
std      14.45663     0.819762     0.815503     0.49995
min       0.00000     0.000000     0.000000     0.00000
25%      12.00000     0.000000     0.000000     0.00000
50%      24.00000     1.000000     1.000000     1.00000
75%      37.00000     2.000000     2.000000     1.00000
max      49.00000     2.000000     2.000000     1.00000
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Raphaele, but this approach is using random iid data and the distribution is normal. Can we assume this on my own data?

Comment: The `train_test_split` with `stratify` option relies in the source code on `StratifyShuffleSplit`. Putting several variables in the `stratify` parameter is equivalent to saying a class is a unique combination of those variables (age, experience, man. exp) and the stratification will be made on this classification variable. The stratification aims at having the same proportions of this classification variable in both samples. So it wont work if some class has only one member for instance (if you only have one row for a specific combination of age, experience and manag experience).

Comment: great answer, Thanks @Raphaele